# React and Vue Google map API remove rendered direction before setting a new one on the map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, vue.js

I use vue-google-maps which is similar to react-google-maps.
Each time I get a new direction to render on the map the old one doesn't removed.

I tried to put `directionsDisplay` as global and used `this.directionsDisplay.setMap(null)` but it didn't removed the old rendered directions.

```
data() {
    return {
      showMap: true,
      coords: {
        lat: 51.507441,
        lng: -0.1277
      },
      destination: {
        lat: 51.527182,
        lng: -0.133992
      },
      waypoints: [],

      currnetWayPointIndex: 0,
//Set directionsDisplay global
      directionsService: {},
      directionsDisplay: {}
    }
  }
```

Get Direction function

```
getDirection() {
      this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
      this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
//Remove old directions
      this.directionsDisplay.setMap(null)
      this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.$refs.map.$mapObject)
      const calculatedWayPoint = this.wayPoints
      // google maps API's direction service
      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(
        directionsService,
        directionsDisplay,
        start,
        destination
      ) {
        directionsService.route(
          {
            origin: start,
            destination,
            waypoints: calculatedWayPoint,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          },
          function(response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              directionsDisplay.setDirections(response)
            } else {
              window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status)
            }
          }
        )
      }
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(
        this.directionsService,
        this.directionsDisplay,
        this.coords,
        this.destination
      )
    },
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irhamkim/20pegws2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution

```
<template>
  <div>
    <gmap-map
      v-show="showMap"
      ref="mapXX"
      :center="coords"
      :zoom="15"
      style="width: 100%; height: 300px"
    >
      <gmap-marker :position="coords"> </gmap-marker>
      <gmap-marker :position="destination"> </gmap-marker>
    </gmap-map>
    <button @click="getDirection">get direction</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
/* global google */
export default {
  directionsService: null,
  directionsDisplay: null,
  data() {
    return {
      showMap: true,
      coords: {
        lat: -7.824374,
        lng: 110.262371
      },
      destination: {
        lat: -7.925665,
        lng: 110.298115
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy().then(() => {
        this.$options.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()
        this.$options.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
        this.$options.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.$refs.mapXX.$mapObject)
      })
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getDirection() {
      this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy().then(() => {
        this.$options.directionsDisplay.set('directions', null)
        this.$options.directionsService.route(
          {
            origin: this.coords,
            destination: this.destination,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
          },
          (result, status) => {
            if (status === 'OK') {
              this.$options.directionsDisplay.setDirections(result)
            }
          }
        )
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

All my preview solutions fails because I did 2 things:
1 I didn't wait until `google` is ready. Now i use `this.$gmapApiPromiseLazy().then(() =>{
//do the magic here
})`
2 I didn't use `directionsService` and `directionsDisplay` in global. Now I use one instance of the map.